# showing wrong time in phpmyadmin using mysql

Tags: mysql, timezone

I am running timestamp related mysql queries in phpmyadmin. There is one table whose name is 'regDate' and 'TIMESTAMP' as datatype. Also I inserted UTC time in it using my php frontend. but when I am running query to show time in IST it adding server time in it. The query is

```
SET time_zone ='+05:30';
SELECT regDate FROM registered WHERE email='xyz@gmail.com';
```

The actual timestamp in table cell is '2016-02-26 04:38:00'.
My server timezone is '-07:00'
And when I am running above query in phpmyadmin it showing me '2016-02-26 17:08:00'.
The output should be '2016-02-26 10:08:00'.
I want to show that UTC time in IST i.e. in +5:30

Comment: Use `CONVERT_TZ()` to convert to a different time zone.

Comment: You can discard the set Time_zone command in Mysql and get the raw time stored in database without alteration. Then echo/print the time using php (set timezone in php)

Comment: but when server get change, it will need to update the timezone in CONVERT_TZ() query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem what is actually happening here is time shown here in your table cell is 04:38:00 which changed to 
17:08:00

because of some process 
04:38:00 + 07:00 = 11:38:00 should be your actual result

but when run the query

`SET time_zone ='+05:30';
SELECT regDate FROM registered WHERE email='xyz@gmail.com';`

this what happens 11:38:00 + 05:30 = 17:08:00

hence your actual result.
'2016-02-26 17:08:00'

Difference your server and Indian time zone is off 1:30

So the following may help

`SET time_zone ='-01:30';`